# Has Youtube removed 'category' from description area?

Tags: web-scraping, youtube

Can someone confirm that **Youtube** has removed the category type from the 'show more / description' area of each video? Our plugin relies on this category being present to help with its functionality. I heard that Youtube was using SO to help with support questions like this, hence why I have posted this here.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They didn't fully remove the feature, you can actually still choose the video category. But it's not visible anymore for viewers.